# Getting 403 error while accessing facebook user profile pic

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook api returns me my facebook profile picture url. I save this url in my db and fetch it from there when I view my profile page. What I'm trying to do is to show facebook profile picture in my profile page of the angularJS application that I'm building.

This is the url that I am getting as response.

```
https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/14100401_286861985019877_63722353171428782_n.jpg?oh=b2bfb6e86553aef6f37989d965e5375e&amp;oe=58584DC1
```

I'm trying to show this something like this.

```
<img src="https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/14100401_286861985019877_63722353171428782_n.jpg?oh=b2bfb6e86553aef6f37989d965e5375e&amp;oe=58584DC1" ng-src="https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/14100401_286861985019877_63722353171428782_n.jpg?oh=b2bfb6e86553aef6f37989d965e5375e&amp;oe=58584DC1" class="img-circle">
```

I fetch it from db and save it in a variable and pass that variable to src, I'm getting a Network error: 403 forbidden.

But when I edit the html from console and hard code the url, it shows.

Why am I facing such an issue?

My facebook app is pretty simple. It has all default permission. that means I can fetch profile picture, right?

Now, the app is in development mode. so the site url I mentioned is something like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/projects/websitename/
```

Is this issue happening because I'm accessing it from localhost?

Comment: Yes. It is most likely because of localhost. Look at the error console

Comment: yeah..maybe.. i'm thinking about going this way. <img src="//graph.facebook.com/{{fid}}/picture?type=large"> @WizKid

Comment: You should not store any URLs to content on Facebook’s CDN for long-time use – they can change at any time.